# Swift TextView becomeFirstResponder auto cleaning my TextView Text

Tags: swift

My scenario, Whenever I opened my `viewcontroller` `becomeFirstResponder` enable to showing keyboard but I don’t want to clear my text because I am passing text from `VC_A` to `VC_B`, So inside `VC_B` I need to edit that passed value. Here, I am getting always data clear. How to stop data clearing and show keyboard.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.fromtextView_editor.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

Comment: From what you have given us so far, there is no reason for you to face the issue you are facing. Which means, the problems is definitely somewhere else. Post the rest of your code.

Comment: How are you passing data from VC_A to VC_B and assigning the value to the textview?